# Error in shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, kml

I have been provided a set of shapefiles (a couple of thousand).  I don't own any GIS software but I would like to convert the shapes to KML and Google's encoded polyline.

I have put the shapefile and associated files online here in a zip file http://www.goo.gl/T5yu6r

However, there appears to be a problem with the original .shp file and I wonder if anyone can confirm it or provide a solution.

When I view it using shp2kml (http://www.zonums.com/shp2kml.html), I can see a GPS trace, but there are no Lat or Lon values (which I do see if I load up a file known to work).

Consequently, the resultant KML file does not work on Google Maps (and confirmed with KML verifiers to contain errors)

I have tried to both view and convert it at Geocommons also, but it does not work.  So, I suspect that the original .shp file is missing some data.  How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I would prefer not to download your zip file so instead could you edit your question to show that you have more than just *.shp files, please?  For example, a shapefile called Roads needs to have at minimum a Roads.shp, Roads.shx and Roads.dbf.

Comment: @PolyGeo, he has only those three. I just opened it in ArcMap.

Comment: Can you give us a hint where the sample data is located on the globe?

Comment: I assume that it is NAD83, because the data set is for Costa Rica...

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are only given the bare minimum files for shapefiles (see post [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70816/a-colleauge-sent-me-an-empty-arcgis-map-document-how-do-i-view-the-data/70821#70821)). You are missing the .prj file, which is used to define which projection your data is in.

Now, a .prj file is simply a text file containing the [well-known text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) representation for a particular coordinate system. If you know which coordinate system your data should be in, you can easily create this file with a text editor.

You can use [spatialreference](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/esriwkt/) to obtain the WKT value that will work for your shapefile. The link goes to WGS84, which might be for what you are looking.

Comment: WGS84 is definitely wrong, with the layer extent being xMin,yMin 527511.00;213358.00 : xMax,yMax 529081.00;216098.00

Comment: Thank you both!  Without having access to the .prj files (they were never provided) can I simply create one using Notepad?  If it is no WGS84, what would it be?

Comment: I assume that it is NAD83, because the data set is for Costa Rica...